# How do I save the value of a variable?

Tags: swift, button, var

Here is a brief explanation of my code:

```
var myVar = 0

if (button image is equal to "mybutton image") {
    myVar = 1
    print("It works")
} else {
    myVar = 2
    print("Not working")
}

ButtonPress {
    print(myVar)
}
```

The problem here is that when I run the application I see in the console that it prints "it works" but when I press the button `myVar` is equal to `0` again. How do I make sure when I press the button `myVar` will be equal to `1`?

Here is the full code as requested:

```
@IBAction func ThingyButtton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let ButtonImage = myButton.image(for: .normal),
       let Image = UIImage(named: "LoseWeightGreen.png"),
       UIImagePNGRepresentation(ButtonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(Image) {
        thingy = 1
        print("1")
    } else {
        thingy = 2
        print("2")
    }
}

@IBAction func ButtonThingyN(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if(thingy == 1) {
        print("ok")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "let", bundle: nil)
        let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC")as! FirstVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true) 
    } else{
        print("good")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "let", bundle: nil)
        let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC")as! SecondVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)  
    }    
}
```

Comment: can you write the exact code in your question, the issue may be with the scope of the variable `myVar`

Comment: it seems there is some logical error in your code. Please put in exact piece of code here

Comment: I just added the full code please let me know if any more information is needed thank you!

Comment: for me it looks ok. I suggest you search for `thighy` in your class and see whether it's getting assigned some value in between. Also, if you may show us how the `thingy` variable is instantiated.

Comment: Since your real code is completely different from your fake, initial example, please redo your question with only the real code and clearly explain what is wrong with the real code.

Comment: Thingy is declared like that var Thingy = 0

Comment: As I see here you have two buttons ThingyButtton and ButtonThingyN, ThingyButtton is used to set the value while ButtonThingyN is used to print the results accordingly, your code seem fine all you need to do is that you need to tap the ThingyButtton before ButtonThingyN or simply give correct value to var thingy = 1

Comment: Hello Ussaid Iqbal that's exactly what I do but for some reason when I press ButtonThingyN the value that I see on the Variable is 0 I always press ThingyButton first it's on different VC

Comment: A real easy way to debug would be to use `didSet` and check where it is being set to 0.

Comment: Okay, for that you need to store variable on first view controller as userdefaults or Preferences, and then get that value on other view-controller the value wont be 0.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like thingy is being set to 1 or 2 only when I press the ThingyButton but then when I press ButtonThingyN it's back to 0 probably because it's outside. So how do I store it in userdefualts or preferences?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i explained in my comment you need a little different logic here try using switch instead of if else as followed,

```swift
@IBAction func ThingyButtton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let ButtonImage = myButton.image(for: .normal),
       let Image = UIImage(named: "LoseWeightGreen.png"),
       UIImagePNGRepresentation(ButtonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(Image) {
        defaults.set(1, forKey: "thingy")
        defaults.synchronize()
        print("1")
    } else {
        defaults.set(2, forKey: "thingy")
        defaults.synchronize()

        print("2")
    }
}



@IBAction func ButtonThingyN(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if defaults.object(forKey: "thingy") != nil {
          let thingy = defaults.integer(forKey: "thingy")
          let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "let", bundle: nil)
          switch thingy{
              case 1:
                  var moveTo = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC") as! FirstVC
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(moveTo, animated: true)

                  break
              case 2:
                 var moveTo = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(moveTo, animated: true)

                  break
              default:
                  print("Thingy value is \(thingy)")
                  return
          }
     }



}
```

Comment: Why would you first create a view controller for `"FirstVC"` and then use a `switch` to create another view controller, throwing away the first one? This makes no sense.

Comment: If u see the comment it says add default view-controller assuming he might have some default view-controller and he can remove return and add break just

Comment: Answers should be self contained and not rely on comments.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it using UserDefaults

Simply I just set userdefults to 1 and 2 and then checked for them using if statement!